# Cannot get Login to work on Android

Tags: php, android

I recently worked with a PHP script that is supposed to hash the password on registration from the android app. The password will hash and be added to the database, but it won't let me login now. There are no error codes coming up either. Here is the code from Android:

```
public LoginRequest( String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("username", username);
```

Here is the PHP script I am supposed to use:

```
    <?php
    require("./Password.php");

    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

    $typeusername = $_POST["username"];
    $typepassword = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $phone, $username, $password, $email);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (password_verify($typepassword, $password)) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $name;
            $response["phone"] = $phone;
            $response["username"] = $username;
            $response["password"] = $password;
            $response["email"] = $email;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Update: This is based off of a template for a login PHP file with a few modifications for my needs. This is closer to what the original template looked like:

```
    <?php
    require("./Password.php");

    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colPhone, $colUsername, $colPassword, $colEmail);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $colName;
            $response["phone"] = $colPhone;
            $response["username"] = $colUsername;
            $response["password"] = $colPassword;
            $response["email"] = $colEmail;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This is supposed to work with a previous database that I had setup for a tutorial series that this template is based on, but it does not work either. With a regular login PHP code, I can login just fine, but I want to be able to use the hashed passwords in my database.

Comment: Make sure the variables are being correctly assigned. Check their values (specially `$password`)

Comment: I know you probably changed it, but it's worth checking. In your previous question, you used `name, username, age, password` as table columns.

Comment: Also make sure your `./Password.php` isn't supposed to be `password.php`.

Comment: Yes, I did change it since then. The last one was just a tutorial, this one is for an actual app I am working on.

Comment: I tried using just Password.php, but it creates an error saying it can't find the file, so I need the ./ in front for it to even read it.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Get Postman extension for chrome and 'forge' some requests. Try getting the php part to work as expected first...

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. For some reason, it just started working. Not sure what I did, but I can login now no issue. +1 for dumb luck I guess.